# Set start position of robot within amcl

Tags: ros, transform, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm working with a mobile robot. Every time I start it I have to start at the same point(the point which is the origin in the map_server map config file). But I want to save the last position of the base_link(to a file for example, no problem with that) when I shutdown the system to let him know at restarting where it was. Is there any way to set a default value for a transform beetween 2 frames with tf2?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315517/set-start-position-of-robot-within-amcl/) by [FaliRey](https://answers.ros.org/users/40001/falirey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-02-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-13**:
This is not really anything to do with the TF2 system, but the localisation system that is being used on the robot. There will probably be a method to set the initial pose of the robot there.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-02-13**:
do you use your own localisation system, or something provided as debian pkg, like `amcl`? If you let us know, we can help more.

**Comment by [FaliRey](https://answers.ros.org/users/40001/falirey/) on 2019-02-13**:
Yes, sorry, I use amcl localisation system with a front laser.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-02-15**:
FYI: I took the liberty of rephrasing your question to better reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For [`amcl`](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) you have to options:

Publish to `initalpose` (after startup) or set the `intial_pose_x/y/a` parameters (before startup of `amcl`). Check the wiki for details.

You can obviously use those by writing your own node which does the saving to file, loading from file and publish/set parameters. Only thing to somehow keep track of is wether this has the desired effect, i.e. some kind of state checking which distinguishes between "amcl started, but at origin location" and "amcl started and read start parameters / got initialpose". As both, setting the parameters before `amcl` starts and sending to a topic is not easy to get feedback on, you'd need to be creative :-)

Edit:

actually, there is a third option, which is calling the `set_map` service. This allows you to send a map together with the inital pose. As this is a service, you'll receive notifications about wether this has been successfull.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2